# Redirecttion error in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have this in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It should work fine but give me error

http://www.website.com/public_html/
Not Found

The requested URL /public_html/ was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an Error Document to handle the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root is`public_html` so www.website.com goes to that folder as the document root.

Comment: That is true Difster but its gives me an error "Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an Error Document to handle the request." when I have all webpage loaded and work perfectly when I go for www.website.com but gives error when go for website.com

Comment: In your Apache config file, is your document root configured correctly?

Comment: Yes, It works fine for all other webs on my server....Having issues only with this web

Answer (score 0):

## Force www:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Hey Parth, DId it but still getting error when go for website.com it redirect me to www.website.com/public_html with error "Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an Error Document to handle the request."

Comment: for taht you have to create rewrite rule.please check this link http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/how-to/set-404-via-htaccess

Comment: ErrorDocument 404 /error/404page.html